# Understanding/Writing C code for Assembly with single precision floating point numbers

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I am having trouble deciphering this given Assembly code:

```
1 unknown5:
2    pxor   %xmm0, %xmm0
3    movl   $0, %eax
4    jmp    .L13
5  .L14:
6    movss  (%rdx,%rax,4), %xmm1
7    mulss  (%rsi,%rax,4), %xmm1
8    addss  %xmm1, %xmm0
9    addq   $1, %rax
10 .L13:
11   cmpq   %rdi, %rax
12   jb .L14
13   rep ret
```

What I *think* is going on:

- 1: function named unknown5()
- 2: sets the floating point return register to 0
- 3: sets the 32-bit return register to 0
- 4: jumps to 10:
- 11: if %rdi > %rax, go to 5:, else go to 13:
- 6: %xmm1 = %rdx+%rax+4
- 7: %xmm1 *= %rsi+%rax+4
- 8: %xmm0 += %xmm1
- 9: %rax += 1
- 13: return %eax, %rax, or %xmm0??

What I have no clue of is what the possible parameters are of the function, nor what each register is representing. I know %rdi, %rsi, and %rdx are first, second, and third parameters (that might be floating point pointers due to single precision operations?), and %xmm0, %xmm1 are first and second floating point parameters (OR local variables?). I also know %rax is the 64-bit return register, but am unsure why it is used here as such. Could someone please elaborate and correct my comprehension? Thank you.

Comment: Assembly doesn't have "local variables", you're thinking of "registers".

Comment: I know, I should have clarified that I need to convert the above Assembly into C, so the registers would either be representing the function parameters or local variables depending

Comment: With a little experience you will come to recognize this as a typical `while` loop.

Comment: Fun fact: this appears to have been compiled by `gcc -O1` (`mov $0, %eax` instead of `xor %eax,%eax`, and the jump into the loop for the first iteration instead of hoisting the first check), with some GCC version older than GCC8 or so (`rep ret` because its `-mtune=generic` default still cares about AMD K8/K10 (e.g. Phenom II and older)).  Also actual `gcc`, not `g++`, because `g++ -O1 / -O0` tends to make dumb "while" loops with a conditional branch at the top ([Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926))

Answer (score 2):

A few hints:

- `%xmm0, %xmm1` are used to pass floating-point parameters, if the function actually takes any.  But are the values they had on entry to the function actually used in any way?
- Don't think about `%rax` as inherently being "a return register".  It's just a register.  If the function is meant to return an integer or pointer then yes, `%rax` (or one of its sub-registers) is where that return value will go, but in the meantime it's just a register that the code can use as it likes, like a local variable as you say.  Same goes for `%xmm0`.
- Your guess about `%rdx` and `%rsi` being pointers is a good one, given how they are used in the `movss/mulss` memory operands.  Where exactly are these instructions loading values from?  On the other hand, `%rdi` does not appear in such a context; how is it used instead?

  Note `movss (%rdx,%rax,4), %xmm1` doesn't set `%xmm1` equal to the value gotten by multiplying `%rax` by 4 and adding `%rdx`.  Rather, it uses `%rdx+%rax*4` as an *address*, fetches a single-precision float from that address in memory, and loads it into `%xmm1`.  That's what the `( )` signify - an indirect memory reference.  If you like, it's the rough equivalent of the unary `*` dereference operator in C.

  Likewise, the value being multiplied in the following `mulss` is also fetched from memory.
- There's no certain way to tell from the code alone whether it's intended to return an `int` (return value in `%eax`) or `long` (`%rax`) or `float/double` (`%xmm0`).  But you can take a very good guess.  Think about the values that each of those registers has when the function returns.  Which seems more plausible as a value for the function to be computing for its caller?

  Notice there are no instructions in this function that write to memory, so it has no "side effects"; its sole purpose must be to compute and return some value.
- This function appears to be performing a familiar mathematical operation.  Can you tell what it is?

Comment: 1) What I'm confused about is can't they also be used for local variables in the C code (e.g. float foo = 3.0;)? And depending on how Assembly utilizes the registers is how one determines the differences?
2) Ahh this clears up a lot of confusion with %rax, thanks!
3) So %rdi may be a passed-in integer, while the others may be float pointers? And am completely lost on where they may be loading their values from.
4) So I guess it would return %xmm0 since they are single precision floating points?
5) Not until I figure more out haha.

Comment: Sure, a register is nothing more than a place to keep a bunch of bits, and from which the CPU can perform various operations on those bits.  Whether you think of those bits as representing a function parameter, or the value of a local variable, or some intermediate value in a computation, or some other piece of useful/useless data, is entirely up to your own imagination and the calling conventions.

Comment: @Pharros: Ah, I think you're confused about 6 and 7.  `movss  (%rdx,%rax,4), %xmm1` doesn't set `%xmm1` equal to the value gotten by multiplying `%rax` by 4 and adding `%rdx`.  Rather, it uses `%rdx+%rax*4` as an *address*, fetches a single-precision float from that address in memory, and loads it into `%xmm1`.  That's what the `( )` signify - an indirect memory reference.  If you like, it's the rough equivalent of the unary `*` dereference operator in C.